# Hide/show table columns in SAPUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, sapui5

I have table and button:

```
    <Panel>
        <content>
            <Button class="btn editTable"></Button>
        </content>
    </Panel>
    <Table id="Listing" class="tableList" mode="MultiSelect" items="{path: 'masterData>/contactsList'}">
        <columns>
            <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                <Text text="{i18n>vendorNum}"/>
            </Column>
            <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                <Text text="{i18n>recipientType}"/>
            </Column>
            <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                <Text text="{i18n>eMail}"/>
            </Column>
        </columns>

        <items>
            <ColumnListItem>
                <cells>
                    <Text text="{masterData>vendorNum}"/>
                </cells>
                <cells>
                    <Text text="{masterData>recipientType}"/>
                </cells>
                <cells>
                    <Text text="{masterData>eMail}"/>
                </cells>
            </ColumnListItem>
        </items>
    </Table>
```

I want at click of a button show up menu with a list of column names. This menu contains a checkboxes that will hide/show table columns. How to do it? Is there any standard tools in SAPUI for this?

[image]

Comment: If you still want to use `sap.m.Table`, they also have a p18n dialog. See this example https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TablePerso/preview

Comment: @Marc, I encountered a problem using your example, described it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35984224/personalization-table-in-sapui5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the personalization (p13n) controller / dialog.

See the examples for [Table](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TablePerso/preview) and [SmartTable](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.personalization.example1/code/Example.view.xml).