# Personalization table in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I saw an  [this](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TablePerso/preview) expamle, and I want to play it at me.

This is my xml view:

```
        <Panel>
            <content>
                <Button press="onPersoButtonPressed" class="btn editTable"></Button>
            </content>
        </Panel>
        <Table id="Listing" class="tableList" mode="MultiSelect" items="{path: 'masterData>/contactsList'}">
            <columns>
                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <Text text="{i18n>vendorNum}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <Text text="{i18n>recipientType}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <Text text="{i18n>eMail}"/>
                </Column>
            </columns>

            <items>
                <ColumnListItem>
                    <cells>
                        <Text text="{masterData>vendorNum}"/>
                    </cells>
                    <cells>
                        <Text text="{masterData>recipientType}"/>
                    </cells>
                    <cells>
                        <Text text="{masterData>eMail}"/>
                    </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
            </items>
        </Table>
```

And this is my controller:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/core/routing/History",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/ui/test/controller/TopMenu.controller",
    "sap/m/TablePersoController",
    "sap/ui/model/resource/ResourceModel"
], function (Controller,History,JSONModel,TopMenu,ResourceModel,TablePersoController) {
    "use strict";
    jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.util.Export");
    jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.util.ExportTypeCSV");
return Controller.extend("sap.ui.test.controller.MasterData", {
    onInit : function () {
        var oData = {
            contactsList:[
                {
                    vendorNum: '101938',
                    recipientType: 'Promo',
                    supplierName: 'Company name'
                },
                {
                    vendorNum: '101936',
                    recipientType: 'Abcd',
                    supplierName: ''
                },
                {
                    vendorNum: '101933',
                    recipientType: 'Xyz',
                    supplierName: 'Comp.Name',
                    beCode: '0108'
                }
            ]
        };

        var oModel = new JSONModel(oData);
        this.getView().setModel(oModel, "masterData");
        var i18nModel = new ResourceModel({
            bundleName: "sap.ui.lenta.i18n.i18n"
        });
        this.getView().setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");

        this._oTPC = new TablePersoController({
            table: this.getView().byId("Listing"),
            componentName: "test"
        }).activate();
    },
    onPersoButtonPressed: function (oEvent) {
        this._oTPC.openDialog();
    },

    onTablePersoRefresh : function() {
        //DemoPersoService.resetPersData();
        this._oTPC.refresh();
    },

    onTableGrouping : function(oEvent) {
        this._oTPC.setHasGrouping(oEvent.getSource().getSelected());
    },

    //.....
```

That example throwing an error: `Uncaught Error: Property "appDescription" does not exist in ManagedObject sap.m.TablePersoController#__controller0`. In this case, the string `" description ":" {{app Description}} "` present in manifest.json, and description string exist in `i18n.properties`.

I can not figure out what I missed? How to make that this code worked? Or do I need to use something else to solve the problem with the actions of the table-columns?

Comment: Can you add the code in a jsbin example? Would be difficult to identify the root cause without real code example

Comment: @Veeraraghavan, The problem occurs if you add the line `"sap/ui/test/controller/TopMenu.controller"`. Here, as I understand it trouble is not in the main code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created wrong mapping of object names with class names.

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/core/routing/History",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/ui/test/controller/TopMenu.controller",
    "sap/m/TablePersoController",
    "sap/ui/model/resource/ResourceModel"
], function (Controller,History,JSONModel,TopMenu,TablePersoController, ResourceModel) {
    "use strict";
```

Here ResourceModel object should be interchanged with TablePersoController as mentioned above.

Because TablePersoController was referring to class mentioned for ResourceModel, it was not properly working.

Change the order and the error should be resolved.